# How to stop rotation of the labels in ant design Donut Chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd, ant-design-pro

I want to stop the rotation of the labels inside the ant design donut chart, all labels inside the ant design chart are should be prallel to the X-axis.

```
const config = {
    legend: { position: labelPosition },
    appendPadding: 10,
    data,
    angleField: "value",
    colorField: "type",
    color: colors,
    radius: 1,
    innerRadius: 0.6,
    label: {
        type: "inner",
        offset: "-50%",
        content: "{value}",
        style: {
            textAlign: "center",
            fontSize: 14,
        },
    },
    statistic: {
        content: {
            style: {
                whiteSpace: "pre-wrap",
                overflow: "hidden",
                textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                color: "#342d31",
            },
            content: content,
        },
    },
};
```

[Description Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db2t2.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can add `autoRotate: false` into the `label` config

```
const config = {
    legend: { position: labelPosition },
    appendPadding: 10,
    data,
    angleField: "value",
    colorField: "type",
    color: colors,
    radius: 1,
    innerRadius: 0.6,
    label: {
        type: "inner",
        offset: "-50%",
        content: "{value}",
        autoRotate: false,
        style: {
            textAlign: "center",
            fontSize: 14,
        },
    },
    statistic: {
        content: {
            style: {
                whiteSpace: "pre-wrap",
                overflow: "hidden",
                textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                color: "#342d31",
            },
            content: content,
        },
    },
};
```

https://ant-design-charts.antgroup.com/en/api/plots/pie#label

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).